# Crystal Reports - massive change table name or edit SQL Server query at runtime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have 170+ reports and our customer would like to decrypt some of data.

For example: report returns first/last name with address, Personal Identification Number etc.

What I need to do is somehow massively change all reports table name, from `Contact` to `Contact_R` (which already include encrypted data) OR maybe there is any way to create something like trigger but in SQL Server, so I could edit query (with replace table name) before it will be executed, fe.

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Contact
```

becomes

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Contact_R
```

Comment: are you using SQL or tables in crystal report datasource connection?

Comment: @Siva Yes, I have defined connection and tables/relations